# Error al crear archivo php

Tags: php, visual-studio, vscode

Tengo Visual studio code, e instale el XAMMP pero al crear un nuevo archivo php sale esto, ya se instalo la extencion PHP Extension Pack

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sale ese error de write abajo

gracias

Comment: Pues es windows diciéndote que modificar o crear cosas en `Archivos de Programa` es algo que Windows no es muy feliz haciendo porque asume que es un virus modificando los programas. O le añades una excepción o configuras xampp para que lea tus proyectos de una carpeta que no esté por allá adentro

Comment: y como hago eso por el XAMMP?